# i want to echo newly submitted value to database to the next page

Tags: php, session

i do have a login system which is loggin in successfully.

after a successful login.. the user submit a form value to another table called  " info"  in database which is submitting successfully.

all i want is that,  the new form value submitted to table "info" in database should print on the next page " account-tr.php"

here is my html table

```
<form action="sub.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
  <p>price
    <label for="price"></label>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
  </p>
  <p>size
    <input type="text" name="size" id="size">
  </p>
  <p>location
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location">
  </p>
  <p>type
    <input name="type" type="text" id="type">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
    <label for="user_id"></label>
    <input name="user_id" type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<?php echo "" . $_SESSION['id'] . ""; ?>">
  </p>
</form>
```

this is my insert.php code

```
<?php 
include ("config.php");
$user_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']);
$price=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['price']);
$size=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['size']);
$location=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['location']);
$type=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['type']);

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_names(user_id,price,size,location,type)
VALUES('$_POST[user_id]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[size]','$_POST[location]','$_POST[type]')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
header ("location:account-tr.php");
?>
```

the is my select statement

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_names WHERE user_id='" . $_SESSION[ "user_id" ] . "' ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 0, 1");
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); ?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="*****"; // Mysql username 
$password="*****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="****"; // Database name  
$tbl_name="info"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 
?>
```

Comment: Why are you sanitizing `$_SESSION` data instead of your `$_POST` data, and then using the raw `$_POST` data in your query?

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded and inside all pages using sessions? If it isn't add it; it's required.

Comment: need your assist so i can achieve my goal

Comment: You're using `$tbl_names` that should be `$tbl_name`

Comment: `action="sub.php"` and `my insert.php code` don't line up -> `sub.php` != `insert.php`

Answer (score 0):

Save the value(s) you want to display on the next page in a session variable. Something like this:

```
$_SESSION['stuff'] = $what_you_want_to_save;
```

Then on the page they are redirect to, you can do something like this:

```
echo "<p>They save this info: $_SESSION[stuff].</p>";
```

Comment: ....i have done that but i am still getting error. i think the error is coming from my select statament... can you look it up for me please

Comment: Nothing in your question suggests there is an SQL error involved.

Comment: thanks @dwayne towell... i have figure out. i used timestamp to pull newest record submitted to database